# Multiple API calls competing for one atomic db action

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0, race-condition

I have an API to send message and create contact as such: when it is called and detected no such contact in the database, it first creates a contact, then send out the message.

The problem is: when multiple API calls are issued concurrently (sending message to the same receiver), multiple contacts of the same receiver will be created. (race condition)

Say A, B and C are issued concurrently, when A is still createing a contact, B and C already detect there is no such contact in the contact list, hence B and C would also create the contact.

Any clue on how to solve such race condition? I used azure sql database, .net6, EF core framework, etc.

I tried using Semaphore, but Semaphore is intraprocess, multiple API calls are interprocess.

I also tried using named mutex

```
            _mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\MyUniqueMutexName", out bool hasInitialOwnership);
            try
            {
                if (!hasInitialOwnership)
                {
                    _mutex.WaitOne();
                }
                res = await CriticalAction(...params...);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (hasInitialOwnership)
                {
                    _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
            }
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Use  Azure queues or Azure Bus and put in queue the requests and process them on by one and in this way u ensure the concurrent process and solve the race condition.

Comment: [Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)? Don't you know them or don't they work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, eventually solved with redis lock